# How do I write this function without using if or switch statements (except for validity check/variable guard check)?

Tags: c, if-statement

As I mentioned in the instructions, I need to write this function without using any if statements other than for validity checks/variable guard checks. But I'm having trouble determining whether or not my code fits this specification. And if my code doesn't work, how would I write it without using the prohibited if statements?

Here's the problem:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
int badgePoly(int x, int y) {
   int mavenbadge, incirclebadge, herobadge, weatherbadge, inquattrobadge,
      bronzebadges, polybadge;

   if ((x >= 1 && x <= 20) && (y >= 1 && y <= 20)) {
      mavenbadge = badgeBoundaryMaven(x, y);     
      incirclebadge = badgeInnerCircle(x, y); 
      herobadge = badgeLocalHero(x, y);
      weatherbadge = badgeBoringWeather(x, y); 
      inquattrobadge = badgeInQuattro(x, y); 
      bronzebadges = mavenbadge + incirclebadge + herobadge + weatherbadge +
         inquattrobadge;   
      if (bronzebadges >= 2) {
         polybadge = 1;
      }
      else {
         polybadge = 0;
      }
   }
   else {
      polybadge = -1;
   }

   return polybadge;
}
```

NOTE: mavenbadge, incirclebadge, herobadge, weatherbadge, and inquattrobadge are all the different types of bronze badges that you can earn in a field (x, y); and bronzebadges is just the sum of all of these to find total number of bronze badges in a field (x, y).

Comment: You should reduce the general indentation by writing `if ((x < 1) || (x > 20) || (y < 1) || (y > 20)) return -1;` and not bothering with accolades and `else`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple. Replace this:

```
if (bronzebadges >= 2) {
    polybadge = 1;
} else {
    polybadge = 0;
}
```

With this:

```
polybadge = (bronzebadges >= 2);
```

Now, obviously if one of the *`badgeXXX`* functions uses if statements you'll need to do more, but I can't help you with that without the code.

Comment: Note: in my opinion, this isn't even a "challenge", this is the way it *should* be written from the beginning, without trying to conform to some arbitrary limitation on what you can and cannot use. Using an `if/else` to set some variable to either 1 or 0 is a powerful [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: @unwind I'm suspecting the actual challenge is in the *`badgeXXX`* functions, but the asker did not post code/specifications for them.

Comment: A real "challenge" would be to do this in one line. This can be done, no need for temporary variables, just using a ternary :D (and the smaller functions of course ^^")

Comment: @Eregrith A ternary is a hidden `if` statement, so is not allowed, at least in my opinion. And how is doing it in one line a challenge? Just delete the newlines.

Comment: @nightcracker A ternary is arguably equal to a hidden if, but the assignment does not explicitly forbid if-like-code. By one line I meant one statement, not a minified version.

Comment: `return ((x < 1) || (x > 20) || (y < 1) || (y > 20)) ? (-1) : ((badgeBoundaryMaven(x, y) + badgeInnerCircle(x, y) + ... ) >= 2);`

Answer (score 0):

Without using the comparison operator:

```
polybadge = !!(bronzebadges & ~1);
```

nightcracker's version is more sane though.